# How to replace variable string using SED

Tags: bash, groovy, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to replace a keyword from a bash on jenkins groovy via pipeline, however the keyword I need to replace is also recognized as a variable .

```
sh """#!/bin/bash

ENV = "poc"
task = "sleep"

sed -i "s/${ENV}/${task}/g" task.txt

"""
```

> Result from my logs shows:

```
+ sed -i s/poc/sleep/g task.txt
```

> If possible I need to consider ${ENV} as **NOT** a variable and treat is a an ordinary string.
>
> how can it possibly replaced to the word **${ENV}** TO **sleep**

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
sed -i 's/${ENV}/sleep/g' task.txt
```